# Blank Web Part Page and search

Tags: 2010, search, publishing-page

I have added a  publishing page to my site. I have set the layout to "Blank Web Part Page". If I add a Content Editor web part will the content be indexed and will it appear in the search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming your search is working properly.  Exactly when it appears would depend on your crawl schedules.